# get selected value from another php page

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

How can I obtain selected value from the select list? How can I named each option? I use array to check availability and post back into index.php but I cannot obtain the selected value because did not named the selected value.

filter.php

```
$a=array(10,12,14,16,18,20);

      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $r=$row['res_time'];
                if($r==12) $a[1] = 0;
                else if($r==14) $a[2] = 0; 
                else if($r==16) $a[3] = 0;
                else if($r==18) $a[4] = 0;
                else if($r==20) $a[5] = 0; 
           } 
            echo'<label> Time:  <select class="form-control" >';
    for($x = 0; $x < count($a); $x++) {
        if($a[$x]!=0) echo '<option>' .$a[$x] . '</option>';
        else{
    echo 'Full';}
}


            echo'</select> </label>';
      }  
      else  
      {  
            echo '<label> Time: <select class="form-control" >';
    for($x = 0; $x < count($a); $x++) {
        if($a[$x]>0) echo '<option >' .$a[$x] . '</option>';
}
            echo'</select></label> </div>'; }
```

Comment: you name the `select` tag, not the `option`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you wanted to select a file type for some kind of uploaded file...

```
<form method="post" action="/path/to/action">
    <select name="fileType">
       <option value="" selected>Please choose a file type</option>
       <option value="msword">Microsoft Word Document</option>
       <option value="pdf">PDF (Portable Document Format)</option>
       <option value="img">An image file<option>
    </select>
</form>
```

When a users submits the form, you will receive the value as `$_POST['fileType']`.

So if they select "Microsoft Word Document" this:

```
echo $_POST['fileType'];
```

would output

```
msword
```

Comment: but in my code is use array as option value so I cannot named the option value? I try to name the select but when I run my code, will show undefined variable because I haven't select the time.